# Тестирование при использовании паттерна Repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, юнит-тесты

Необходимо протестировать метод `GetReportListForSchool`:

**Repository.cs**

```
public class ReportRepository : IReportRepository
{
    private monit95Context db;
    public ReportRepository(monit95Context db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }
    public List<Report> GetReportListForSchool(school _school)
    {
        List<Report> result = new List<Report>();
        foreach (var report in db.Reports)
        {
            string catalog = String.Format(@"{0}\{1} - {2}", report.path, _school.AreaID, _school.area.AreaName);
            string[] rarFiles = Directory.GetFiles(catalog, "*.rar")
                                         .Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path))
                                         .ToArray(); //получить список rar-файлов, т.е. коды школ
            if (Array.IndexOf(rarFiles, _school.SchoolID) != -1)
            {
                result.Add(report);
            }

        }

        return result.ToList();
    }
}
```

И здесь сразу первый вопрос:

**1. Если у меня репозиторий работает с базой отчетов, правильно ли я поместил метод по поиску всех отчетов по школе именно в класс `ReportRepository`?**

Вот часть кода из юнит-теста:

**UnitTest.cs**

```
    public void TestGetReportListForSchool()
    {
        //Организация
        IReportRepository reportRepository = new ReportRepository(new monit95Context());
        school _school = new school() //создаю школу
        {
            SchoolID = "0286",
            AreaID = 205
        };

        //Действие
        var reportList = reportRepository.GetReportListForSchool(_school);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, reportList.Count);
    }
```

Хотел проверить на количество возвращаемых отчетов. Но это не сработало т.к. при компиляция вышло сообщение о том, что нет строки подключения (context). Поиск в сети на вел на мысль, что необходимо использовать `Mock-объект` и здесь вопрос номер

**2. Как в моем случаи, используя библиотеку `Moq` провести тестирование метода `GetReportListForSchool`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если `monit95Context` -- это EF-контекст, который наследуется от `DbContext`, то убедитесь, что свойство `Reports` -- виртуальное. В таком случае вы сможете замокать с помощью Moq сам контекст и содержимое `Reports`. Подробнее можно почитать [на MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429.aspx).

```
public void TestGetReportListForSchool()
{
    // вместо Report подставьте свой тип отчета
    var reports = new List<Report>()
    {
        new Report() { ... },
        new Report() { ... }
    }.AsQueryable();

    var reportsMock = new Mock<DbSet<Report>>();
    reportsMock.As<IQueryable<Report>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(reports.Provider);
    reportsMock.As<IQueryable<Report>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(reports.Expression);
    reportsMock.As<IQueryable<Report>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(reports.ElementType);
    reportsMock.As<IQueryable<Report>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(0 => reports.GetEnumerator());

    var contextMock = new Mock<monit95Context>();
    contextMock.Setup(c => c.Reports).Returns(reportsMock.Object);

    //Организация
    IReportRepository reportRepository = new ReportRepository(contextMock.Object);
    school _school = new school() //создаю школу
    {
        SchoolID = "0286",
        AreaID = 205
    };

    //Действие
    var reportList = reportRepository.GetReportListForSchool(_school);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, reportList.Count);
}
```

Однако мока контекста и списка отчетов недостаточно. Ваш метод также работает с файловой системой. Поэтому вам надо либо в начале теста создавать нужные файлы на диске, либо выносить функциональность работы с файловой системой в отдельную зависимость и мокать эту зависимость. Второй способ предпочтительнее.